# pandas data-frame continuously update

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

please see the pandas based Patten scanner, here i am using csv as data source and loading the same in to data.

since data is loading from csv file, i have to reload/rerun the script every 5 min to read the updated csv file hence repeating the plot every 5min.

is there any way to use  df.update to avoid reloading of the script and prevent the reloading of plot again and again.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from harmonic_functions import *
import uuid
from csv import DictReader


data = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')



data.time = pd.to_datetime(data.time,format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
data.index = data['time']
# data = data.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

price = data.close.copy()

err_allowed = 10.0/100

pnl = []
trade_dates=[]
correct_pats=0
pats=0

# plt.ion()

for i in range (100,len(price)):

    current_idx,current_pat,start,end = peak_detect(price.values[:i],order=7)

    XA = current_pat[1] - current_pat[0]
    AB = current_pat[2] - current_pat[1]
    BC = current_pat[3] - current_pat[2]
    CD = current_pat[4] - current_pat[3]

    moves = [XA,AB,BC,CD]

    gart = is_gartley(moves,err_allowed)
    butt = is_butterfly(moves,err_allowed)
    bat = is_bat(moves,err_allowed)
    crab = is_crab(moves,err_allowed)
    shark = is_shark(moves,err_allowed)
    trio = is_trio(moves,err_allowed)
    cyph = is_cyph(moves,err_allowed)
    three_dives = is_3dives(moves, err_allowed)
    fivezero = is_50(moves, err_allowed)
    altbat = is_altbat(moves, err_allowed)
    deepcrab = is_deepcrab(moves, err_allowed)
    dragon = is_dragon(moves, err_allowed)
    snorm = is_snorm(moves, err_allowed)

    harmonics = np.array([gart,butt,bat,crab,shark,trio,cyph,three_dives,fivezero,altbat,deepcrab,dragon,snorm])
    labels = ['Garterly','Butterfly','Bat','Crab','Shark','Trio','Cypher','3Dives','5Zero','AltBat','DeepCrab','Dragon','Snorm']


    if np.any(harmonics == 1) or np.any(harmonics == -1):
        for j in range (0,len(harmonics)):
            if harmonics[j] == 1 or harmonics[j]==-1:
                pats+=1
                sense = 'Bearish ' if harmonics[j]==-1 else 'Bullish '
                label = sense + labels[j] + ' found' 
                print(label)
                print(price.values[start])

                plt.title(label)
                plt.plot(np.arange(start,i+5),price.values[start:i+5])
                plt.scatter(current_idx,current_pat,c='r')
                filename = str(uuid.uuid1())[:8]
                print(current_pat)
                print(current_idx)
#                with open('temp.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
#                    file = DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
#                    close = str(current_pat[4])
#                    print(current_pat)
#                    rows = [row for row in file if row['close'] in close]
#                    closetime = rows[-1]['ID']
#                   print(closetime)
                write1 = str(current_idx)
                write2 = str(current_pat)
                write = write1 + ',' + write2
                print(write)
                with open("datadb", "r+") as file:
                    for line in file:
                        if write in line:
                            break
                    else:  # not found, we are at the eof
                        file.write(f"{write}\n")  # append missing data
                        print(filename)
                        plt.savefig(filename)
                        plt.close(filename)
#                plt.show()
                plt.clf()
```